# how can I plot with a dot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am wondering whether one can help me to plot my data in this way shown in this figure

[image]

Only in two color showing the data coming from df1 or df2

Y axis, Lets say for the first values of two data frames

df1 is

```
Var1 Freq
1     2  252
```

and df2 is

```
   Var1 Freq
1     2  306
```

So, instead the name in Y axis, I want to be 2 and then a dot in 252 (showing the value of df1) and a dot on 306 (showing the value for df2) and the dark line between the two shows the distance between two values

The range of Var1 for two data is different, so for df1 we have some point which we don't have for df2 and we can just plot one dot for the one that exist

we split the data into three part like Africa, AMrecia and Asia based on Y axis

```
2 to 10
10 to 20 
Higher than 20
```

I can plot it in simple line shape or even freq shape but this plot I found it very difficult and I could not even get a line for it. I would appreciate any help

I first try to merge the data which fails because some data in Var1 does not exist in both

```
m=merge(df1,df2,by="Var1")
```

Comment: The function in base R is `dotchart`.

Comment: They're dumbbell charts @lmo, not dot charts

Comment: @nik you "found it difficult" yet I see no plotting code. what did you actually try? Plus _"I want the Y axis to be the Freq values (between the two dfs) and the X axis to be Freq"_ (unclear at best). and, one data frame has 25 rows and the other 26. and you have differing `Var`s between the data frames. it's no wonder you're having problems. super low-quality question.

Comment: @nik  "I want the Y axis to be the Freq values (between the two dfs) and the X axis to be Freq " isn't clear to me. What defines the points, lines, and colours from your data frames?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I guess that darker line in between the points on each line distinguishes the example figure from a dot chart.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I explained it above, is this clear now ?

Comment: @Spacedman I explained it above, is it clear now?

Comment: @lmo I have clarified it above

Comment: @hrbrmstr to be honest, I could not even find a way to start it and that is why I dont have any code there. There are plenty of ways that I can plot it without any problem but for this case, I cannot sorry if I don't have any code :-(

Comment: Unless you get someone else to _"please code this for me"_ you might consider taking [this hint](https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/0d206070cea01bcb0118) or  [this hint](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggalt/blob/master/R/geom_dumbbell.R#L85-L87) and trying something on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, by='Var1', all=TRUE)
df$Var1 <- as.integer(as.character(df$Var1))
df$Continent <- cut(df$Var1, breaks = c(-Inf, 10, 20, Inf), labels= c('Africa', 'America', 'Asia'))
par(mfrow=c(3,1), mar=c(4,4,1,1), oma=c(1.5,2,1,1))
x.min <- min(c(df$Freq.x, df$Freq.y), na.rm=TRUE)
x.max <- max(c(df$Freq.x, df$Freq.y), na.rm=TRUE)
for (continent in unique(df$Continent)) {
  df3 <- df[df$Continent == continent,]
  plot(df3$Freq.x, df3$Var1, pch=19, col='red', cex=1.2,
       xlim=c(x.min, x.max),
       xlab='Freq', ylab=continent)
  points(df3$Freq.y, df3$Var1, pch=19, col='blue', cex=1.2)
  segments(df3$Freq.x, df3$Var1, df3$Freq.y, df3$Var1, col='gray')
}
title(main="3 Continents of Colonialism", outer=TRUE)
```

[image]

Updated with your new requirement:

```
df <- merge(df1, df2, by='Var1', all=TRUE)
df$Var1 <- as.integer(as.character(df$Var1))
df$Continent <- cut(df$Var1, breaks = c(-Inf, 10, 20, Inf), labels= 

c('Africa', 'America', 'Asia'))
    par(mfrow=c(3,1), mar=c(4,4,1,1), oma=c(1.5,2,1,1))
x.min <- 0
x.max <- c(300, 50, 10)
xlab <- c('', '', 'Freq')
i <- 1
for (continent in unique(df$Continent)) {
  df3 <- df[df$Continent == continent,]
  plot(df3$Freq.x, df3$Var1, pch=19, col='red', cex=1.5,
       xlim=c(x.min, x.max[i]),
       xlab=xlab[i], ylab=continent)
  par(xpd=FALSE)
  grid (lty = 6, col = "cornsilk2")
  par(xpd=TRUE)
  points(df3$Freq.y, df3$Var1, pch=19, col='blue', cex=1.5)
  segments(df3$Freq.x, df3$Var1, df3$Freq.y, df3$Var1, col='gray', lwd = 2)
  i <- i + 1
}
title(main="3 Continents of Colonialism", outer=TRUE)
legend(x=8.6, y=0, legend = c("DF1", "DF2"), 
       col=c("red", "blue"), pch=19, xpd=NA, bty="o")
```

[image]

Comment: can we make Legend for Blue to be DF1 and for Red dots to be DF2?

Comment: added the legends, in case you need to swap the colors it should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

With ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Freq.x, Var1)) + 
  geom_point(col='red') + 
  geom_point(aes(Freq.y, Var1), col='blue') +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=Freq.y, yend=Var1), col='gray') +
  facet_wrap(~Continent, ncol=1, scales = 'free') +
  xlab('Freq') +
  ylab('Var') + 
  ggtitle('3 Continents of Colonialism')+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted and liked your answer. Is it also possible toads the Var for Three of them ? in this example? I will like your answer here too

Comment: you also like my question please if it is possible for you

Comment: already liked your answer , however if you could help me to make it like the figure in my question, I would appreciate it SO MUCH

Comment: actually in this case the continent name is added on top (as title of) each of the facets.